# Saving checkbox value in erb - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox, nested

I have a nested form that saves information to three different models. One section of the form uses checkboxes and is supposed to save values 1-5.  However, even when the boxes are checked the form returns value 0.  I have tried several different variations of code for setting the checked value.  Any help would be much appreciated. A section of the form code is below:

```
<%= form_for @newinstructor do |f|%>

  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :through_ats do |tag_field| %>
    <%= label_tag("What categories does your activity fit into?") %><br>
    <%= label_tag(:tag, "Cooking") %>
    <%= tag_field.check_box(:tag_id, :value => 1) %>
    <%= label_tag(:tag, "Art") %>
    <%= tag_field.check_box(:tag_id, :value => 2) %>
    <%= label_tag(:tag, "Music") %>
    <%= tag_field.check_box(:tag_id, :value => 3) %>
    <%= label_tag(:tag, "Outdoors") %>
    <%= tag_field.check_box(:tag_id, :value => 4) %>
    <%= label_tag(:tag, "Food") %>
    <%= tag_field.check_box(:tag_id, :value => 5) %>
  <% end %>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem I had, I had to uniquely define each of the symbols in tag_field.checkbox, then require/permit them individually in params

so in the form i put:

```
<%= label_tag("Please check off the categories your activity fits into.") %><br>
    <%= label_tag(:tag, "Cooking") %>
    <%= tag_field.check_box(:cooking) %>
    <%= label_tag(:tag, "Art") %>
    <%= tag_field.check_box(:art) %>
```

instead of :

```
<%= label_tag("What categories does your activity fit into?") %><br>
    <%= label_tag(:tag, "Cooking") %>
    <%= tag_field.check_box(:tag_id, :value => 1) %>
    <%= label_tag(:tag, "Art") %>
    <%= tag_field.check_box(:tag_id, :value => 2) %>
```

and in the controller:

```
params.require(:instructor).permit(through_ats: [:cooking, :art, :music, :outdoors, :food])
```

instead of:

```
params.require(:instructor).permit(through_ats: [:id, :tag_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you permit `tag_id` in params?

```
params.require(:instructor).permit(:name,
   through_ats_attributes: [:id, :tag_id, :_destroy]
)
```

Comment: In which file should I permit the tag_id in params?  I just tried adding it to the method in my controller, but that didn't work.

Comment: in ``instructors_controller.rb``` or something like it because I don't know exactly what's your model name.